# & was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file, cmd

hey guys i have problem with this symbol very often {&} usualz im able to use different waz to fix this but today im unable to find and i would like to ask comunity if theres is somethink wrong with my code.

```
making test for wifi card for HP 255 G7
```

echo @%processor_architecture% | find /i "x86" 
    if errorlevel 1 set prikaz=devcon64
    if not errorlevel 1 set prikaz=devcon

```
if exist C:\winfunc\wtool\%cmd%.exe goto next
if exist %cmd%.exe goto next
goto missing    
:start

set CHECK=WLAN
cls
color 07
echo.
cEcho ~0E%CHECK% CHECK
cEcho ~0E============================================================
echo.
echo  Program overi pritomnost wlan karty!
echo.

echo @%processor_architecture% | find /i "x86" 
if errorlevel 1 set prikaz=devcon64
if not errorlevel 1 set prikaz=devcon

if exist C:\winfunc\wtool\%cmd%.exe goto next
if exist %cmd%.exe goto next
goto missing

:next
if exist pom.txt del /Q /F pom.txt
call %cmd% status * | find /i /n "WiFi" | find /i /v "bluetooth" >pom.txt
set row=
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%a in (pom.txt) do set row=%%a

if @%row%==@ goto fail

set row=%row:[=%
set row=%row:]=%
set row=%row: =%
set /a row=%row%+1

call %cmd% status * | find /i /n "driver is running" | find /i "[%row%]"
if not errorlevel 1 goto pass
```

Comment: Where is this error occurring? I don't see a single `&` in your code.

Comment: You did not post all the code.

Comment: You could start by changing `set row=%%a` to `set "row=%%a"`, `if @%row%==@ goto fail` to `if "%row%"=="" goto fail`, `set row=%row:[=%` to `set "row=%row:[=%"`, `set row=%row:]=%` to `set "row=%row:]=%"` and `set row=%row: =%` to `set "row=%row: =%"`.

Comment: Error happenned after row counter: 
set row=%row:[=%
set row=%row:]=%
set row=%row: =%
set /a row=%row%+1

Comment: What's the content of variable `%cmd%`? Don't reply with a comment, [edit] your question instead as it's relevant information!

Comment: thank for your repl. code has been edited variable %cmd% is now on the top of code

Answer (score 0):

ok i got it so nwm my problem ive changed

```
**call %cmd% status * | find /i /N "Realtek RTL8821CE" >pom.txt**
set row=
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%a in (pom.txt) do set row=**"%%a"**
```